# Sorting files using a bash script

Tags: bash

Thank you very much for reading this. I am very new to bash so I need your advice in the following:

I want to write a bash script that would read a file with 2 columns

```
f  2
g  1
s  4
d  5
f  2
g  5
d  9
g  10
h  1
s  5
d  29
```

My script would actually sort this file based on the first column (alphabet) and produce a file called `alpha_sorted.txt` and then I want it to do the same thing for the numbers and name it `numbers_sorted.txt`.

I am very new to this so I would like to ask for your help if possible supplying me with documents or links or even helping out with the code.

The script is meant to be for introductory level so complicating the methods is not advised.

#### Update

Using john1024's answer, I have the following problem:

```
Hasan@HasanChr /cygdrive/c/users/Hasan/Desktop/Bash
$ chmod +x script.sh

Hasan@HasanChr /cygdrive/c/users/Hasan/Desktop/Bash
$ ./script.sh
cat: alpha_sorted.txt: No such file or directory
```

Here is a screenshot of `script.sh`

[image]

Comment: Knowing that i am operating on windows *

Comment: do you *really* want a *pure* bash solution, or do you want to use tools crafted for the purpose such as `sort`? As in: it is possible to write a function doing the sorting in pure bash – but in most cases one would use tools made for the task. The former is far more complex.

Comment: I would probably want to use the most basic solution as in a script in bash ( pure bash ) to do the trick ...

Comment: But of course i can still use sort so its fine two versions would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are better ways to sort](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289237/117549) than to do it purely in bash. This is not a good answer to your question -- it's not simple (because it uses several features of bash that aren't common-place), and it doesn't do things "The Unix Way", which is to use tools that are pre-built for doing one thing and doing it well (such as sorting).

I decided to write this Answer up to help make a larger point that your account's default shell is built to run commands and redirect I/O. Just because a shell has a [multitude of features, like Bash does](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) doesn't mean it's the best tool for a particular job. You'll very often see answers here that suggest using awk or perl (or jq or sort ...) instead of trying to [hack it into a shell-only script](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashWeaknesses).

That being said, bash *can* sort -- it's just not built-in. I'll repeat myself: it's still not a good idea. But you can do it. Below are four functions, implemented in bash, that [sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) two different ways on each of the two fields.

The functions use:

- [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays)
- [local function variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-local)
- [mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile)
- [`for ((` loops](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#index-for)
- complex [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#index-expansion_002c-parameter)
- bash's [`[[` test operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b) for doing the actual sorting
- bash's `[[` test operator for parsing out the two values
- bash's [`read` built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)

The insertion sort is not efficient ([O(n)<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), but certainly reasonable for small datasets, such as the 11-line example. The four functions ran in sub-second time for the sample data, but for a randomly-generated 1,000 line input file, the "separate array" sorts took ~15 seconds while the "in-place" versions took ~60 seconds because of all of the re-processing of the values. Compare this to the [standard sort utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) which sorted the 1,000 line file on either column in sub-thousandths-of-a-second time.

The two "inplace" functions attempt to save a few bytes by creating only one array (and some one-off variables for looping and swapping values); on the plus side, it uses a neat bash function to map file contents into arrays. The "keyed" functions throw caution to the wind and create *two* separate arrays, one for the desired keys to sort on and the other of the actual values.

```
function sort_inplace_f1 {
  local array
  mapfile -t array < "$1"
  local i j tmp
  for ((i=0; i <= ${#array[@]} - 2; i++))
  do
    for ((j=i + 1; j <= ${#array[@]} - 1; j++))
    do
      local ivalue jvalue
      [[ ${array[i]} =~ ([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*) ]]
      ivalue="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      [[ ${array[j]} =~ ([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*) ]]
      jvalue=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      if [[ $ivalue > $jvalue ]]
      then
        tmp=${array[i]}
        array[i]=${array[j]}
        array[j]=$tmp
      fi
    done
  done
  printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
}

function sort_inplace_f2 {
  local array
  mapfile -t array < "$1"
  local i j tmp
  for ((i=0; i <= ${#array[@]} - 2; i++))
  do
    for ((j=i + 1; j <= ${#array[@]} - 1; j++))
    do
      local ivalue jvalue
      [[ ${array[i]} =~ ([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*) ]]
      ivalue="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      [[ ${array[j]} =~ ([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*) ]]
      jvalue=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      if [[ $ivalue > $jvalue ]]
      then
        tmp=${array[i]}
        array[i]=${array[j]}
        array[j]=$tmp
      fi
    done
  done
  printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"
}

function sort_keyed_f1 {
  local c1 c2 keys values
  while IFS=' ' read -r c1 c2
  do
    keys+=("$c1")
    values+=("$c1 $c2")
  done < "$1"

  local i j tmpk tmpv
  for ((i=0; i <= ${#keys[@]} - 2; i++))
  do
    for ((j=i + 1; j <= ${#keys[@]} - 1; j++))
    do
      if [[ ${keys[i]} > ${keys[j]} ]]
      then
        # swap keys
        tmpk=${keys[i]}
        keys[i]=${keys[j]}
        keys[j]=$tmpk
        # swap values
        tmpv=${values[i]}
        values[i]=${values[j]}
        values[j]=$tmpv
      fi
    done
  done
  printf "%s\n" "${values[@]}"
}

function sort_keyed_f2 {
  local c1 c2 keys values
  while IFS=' ' read -r c1 c2
  do
    keys+=("$c2")
    values+=("$c1 $c2")
  done < "$1"

  local i j tmpk tmpv
  for ((i=0; i <= ${#keys[@]} - 2; i++))
  do
    for ((j=i + 1; j <= ${#keys[@]} - 1; j++))
    do
      if [[ ${keys[i]} -gt ${keys[j]} ]]
      then
        # swap keys
        tmpk=${keys[i]}
        keys[i]=${keys[j]}
        keys[j]=$tmpk
        # swap values
        tmpv=${values[i]}
        values[i]=${values[j]}
        values[j]=$tmpv
      fi
    done
  done
  printf "%s\n" "${values[@]}"
}
```

Even after all of that, you *still* need one of your shell's core "functions", that is -- to redirect the output to a file:

```
sort_keyed_f1 input-file > alpha_sorted.txt
sort_keyed_f2 input-file > numbers_sorted.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Since this is posted this on **unix**.stackexchange.com, I am going to assume that you have access to the usual unix tools.

Alphabetic sorting on first column:

```
$ sort file.txt >alpha_sorted.txt
$ cat alpha_sorted.txt
d  29
d  5
d  9
f  2
f  2
g  1
g  10
g  5
h  1
s  4
s  5
```

Numeric sorting:

```
$ sort -nk2,2 file.txt >numbers_sorted.txt
$ cat numbers_sorted.txt
g  1
h  1
f  2
f  2
s  4
d  5
g  5
s  5
d  9
g  10
d  29
```

`-n` specifies numeric sorting.  `-k2,2` specifies sorting on the second column.

For more information, see `man sort`.

#### Problems editing a Unix script with Notepad

I created a script with DOS line-endings:

```
$ cat dos.sh
sort file.txt >alpha_sorted.txt
cat alpha_sorted.txt
```

Although it is not visible, I added a space at the end of the `cat` command.  With this file, I can reproduce the error that you saw:

```
$ chmod +x dos.sh
$ dos.sh
cat: alpha_sorted.txt: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
```

We can correct this problem with a utility such as `dos2unix` or `tr`.  Using `tr`:

```
$ tr -d '\r' <dos.sh >fixed.sh
$ chmod +x fixed.sh
```

Now, we can run the command successfully:

```
$ fixed.sh
d  29
d  5
d  9
f  2
f  2
g  1
g  10
g  5
h  1
s  4
s  5
```

Comment: John, slight nitpicking, `-k2` specifies to start sorting from column 2 to till end, not only on the column 2 (in this case which is only what left but again hey :) )

Comment: @heemayl Very true.  I changed it to `-k2,2`.  While the second `2` is superfluous here, you are probably right that it is better practice to be explicit.

Comment: I do have a small problem, iif i was to put the commands in a text file and change it to .sh how am i suppose to run it since i have been trying to do so for the past few hours and it is not working am using cyguin

Comment: @JavaFreak On a linux machine, you would mark the script as executable with `chmod +x scriptname.sh`, and then run it with `./ scriptname.sh`

Comment: Check my comment below if possible sir

Comment: @JavaFreak Looking at your post, my first guess is that the problem has to do with DOS/Windows line-endings.  DOS ends a line with `\r\n`.  Unix ends a line with just `\n` and treats `\r` like a valid (but invisible) character.  This causes an endless number of subtle problems.  Please try converting your `script.sh` to Unix line endings using a tool like `dos2unix`.  If you use a native Unix editor (`nano` is good for beginners), then you will avoid this as well as other subtle issues.

Comment: @JavaFreak I just transferred the info showing the no-such-file error to your question.  As you have found out, StackExchange takes its format seriously.  The idea is that the question is to contain a _complete_ question and the answers are to contain _only_ answers.

Comment: One can also reproduce the line-endings problem in Notepad by not providing a newline at the end of the `cat alpha_sorted.txt`. Empirically `bash` is happy to infer the newline, and this then also leads to the `alpha_sorted.txt\r` vs `alpha_sorted.txt` mismatch that triggers the reported problem

Comment: @roaima Very true.  Since Windows is not going away, I think it is unfortunate that Unix tools do not have an option to ignore `\r` characters.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. An environment variable to define "nonstandard" line endings perhaps, thereby handling not only Windows but also Mac in one go. `ALLOW_LINE_ENDINGS='\r\n'` handled by `libc` and recommended being set as an appropriate default at login. Mind you, how long would it be before script writers started intentionally abusing it as a shortcut?

Comment: Looks like Cygwin's already thinking about this, see https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html, but it doesn't really default to DWIM. Also, thinking harder about the problem, `libc` wouldn't really know whether a file was text or binary unless `binmode()` had been used - in which case Cygwin already handles it correctly

Comment: @roaima That link is very interesting.  Thanks.  Cygwin knows what the "ideal" behavior would be.  And, they know that the actual behavior, for good reasons or otherwise, is quite different.