# Sort an array of pathnames of files by their basenames

Tags: bash, filenames, sort, array

Suppose that I have list of pathnames of files stored in an array

```
filearray=("dir1/0010.pdf" "dir2/0003.pdf" "dir3/0040.pdf" )
```

I want to sort the elements in the array according to the basenames of the filenames, in numeric order

```
sortedfilearray=("dir2/0003.pdf" "dir1/0010.pdf" "dir3/0040.pdf")
```

How can I do that?

I can only sort their basename parts:

```
basenames=()
for file in "${filearray[@]}"
do
    filename=${file##*/}
    basenames+=(${filename%.*})
done
sortedbasenamearr=($(printf '%s\n' "${basenames[@]}" | sort -n))
```

I am thinking about

- creating an associative array whose keys are the basenames and values are the pathnames, so access to the pathnames is always done via basenames.
- creating another array for basenames only, and apply `sort` to the basename array.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good idea, but you *can* [sort in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289363/117549)

Comment: Careful with an array keyed on the basenames, if you could have dir1/42.pdf and dir2/42.pdf

Comment: That (different pathnames with the same basename) doesn't happen in my case. But if a bash script can deal with it, that will be great. I don't have reasonably good requirements on how to sort pathnames with the same basename, maybe someone else may. `dir1` `dir2` are just made up, and they are actually arbitrary pathnames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to ksh or zsh, bash has no builtin support for sorting arrays or lists of arbitrary strings. It can sort globs or the output of `alias` or `set` or `typeset` (though those last 3 not in the user's locale sorting order), but that can't be used practically here.

There's nothing in the POSIX toolchest that can readily sort arbitrary lists of strings either¹ (`sort` sorts lines, so only short (LINE_MAX being often shorter than PATH_MAX) sequences of characters other than NUL and newline, while file paths are non-empty sequences of bytes other than 0).

So while you could implement your own sorting algorithm in `awk` (using the `<` string comparison operator) or [even `bash`](/a/289363) (using `[[ < ]]`), for arbitrary paths in `bash`, portably, the easiest may be to resort to `perl`:

With `bash4.4+`, you could do:

```
readarray -td '' sorted_filearray < <(perl -MFile::Basename -l0 -e '
  print for sort {basename($a) cmp basename($b)} @ARGV' -- "${filearray[@]}")
```

That gives a `strcmp()`-like order. For an order based on the locale's collation rules like in globs or the output of `ls`, add a `-Mlocale` argument to `perl`. For numeric sort (more like GNU `sort -g` as it supports numbers like `+3`, `1.2e-5` and not thousand separators, though not hexadimals), use `<=>` instead of `cmp` (and again `-Mlocale` for the user's decimal mark to be honoured like for the `sort` command).

You'll be limited by the maximum size of arguments to a command. To avoid that, you could pass the list of files to `perl` on its stdin instead of via arguments:

```
readarray -td '' sorted_filearray < <(
  printf '%s\0' "${filearray[@]}" | perl -MFile::Basename -0le '
    chomp(@files = <STDIN>);
    print for sort {basename($a) cmp basename($b)} @files')
```

With older versions of `bash`, you could use a `while IFS= read -rd ''` loop instead of `readarray -d ''` or get `perl` to output the list of paths properly quoted so you can pass it to `eval "array=($(perl...))"`.

With `zsh`, you can fake a glob expansion for which you can define a sort order:

```
sorted_filearray=(/(e{'reply=($filearray)'}oe{'REPLY=$REPLY:t'}))
```

With `reply=($filearray)` we actually force the glob expansion (which initially was just `/`) to be the elements of the array. Then we define the sort order to be based on the tail of the filename.

For a `strcmp()`-like order, fix the locale to C. For numeric sort (similar to GNU `sort -V`, not `sort -n` which makes a significant difference when comparing `1.4` and `1.23` (in locales where `.` is the decimal mark) for instance), add the `n` glob qualifier.

Instead of `oe{expression}`, you can also use a function to define a sorting order like:

```
by_tail() REPLY=$REPLY:t
```

or more advanced ones like:

```
by_numbers_in_tail() REPLY=${(j:,:)${(s:,:)${REPLY:t}//[^0-9]/,}}
```

(so `a/foo2bar3.pdf` (2,3 numbers) sorts after `b/bar1foo3.pdf` (1,3) but before `c/baz2zzz10.pdf` (2,10))
and use as:

```
sorted_filearray=(/(e{'reply=($filearray)'}no+by_numbers_in_tail))
```

Of course, those can be applied on real globs as that's what they're primarily intended for. For instance, for a list of `pdf` files in any directory, sorted by basename/tail:

```
pdfs=(**/*.pdf(N.oe+by_tail))
```

---

¹ If a `strcmp()`-based sorting is acceptable, and for short strings, you could transform the strings to their hex-encoding with `awk` before passing to `sort` and transform back after sorting.

Comment: See this answer below for a great bash one-liner: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394166/41735

Answer (score 12):

`sort` in GNU coreutils allows custom field separator and key. You set `/` as field separator and sort based on second field to sort on the basename, instead of entire path.

`printf "%s\n" "${filearray[@]}" | sort -t/ -k2` will produce

```
dir2/0003.pdf
dir1/0010.pdf
dir3/0040.pdf
```

Comment: This is a standard option for `sort`, not a GNU extension.  This will work if the paths are all of the same length.

Comment: Same answer in the same time :)

Comment: This works only if the paths contain a single directory each. What about `some/long/path/0011.pdf`? As far as I can see from its man page, `sort` does contains no option to sort by the last field.

Answer (score 6):

```
oldIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'
if [[ -o noglob ]]; then
  setglob=1; set -o noglob
else
  setglob=0
fi

sorted=( $(printf '%s\n' "${filearray[@]}" |
            awk '{ print $NF, $0 }' FS='/' OFS='/' |
            sort | cut -d'/' -f2- ) )

IFS="$oldIFS"; unset oldIFS
(( setglob == 1 )) && set +o noglob
unset setglob
```

Sorting of file names with *newlines* in their names will cause issues at the `sort` step.

It generates a `/`-delimited list with `awk` that contains the basename in the first column and the complete path as the remaining columns:

```
0003.pdf/dir2/0003.pdf
0010.pdf/dir1/0010.pdf
0040.pdf/dir3/0040.pdf
```

This is what is sorted, and `cut` is used to remove the first `/`-delimited column.  The result is turned into a new `bash` array.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas A bit hairy, but ok...

Comment: Note that arguably, it computes the wrong basename for paths like `/some/dir/`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but the OP specifically said he had paths of files, so I'll just assume that there is a proper basename at the end of the path.

Comment: Note that in a typical GNU non-C locale, `a/x.c++ b/x.c-- c/x.c++` would be sorted in that order even though `-` sorts before `+` because `-`, `+` and `/`'s primary weight is _IGNORE_ (so comparing `x.c++/a/x.c++` against `x.c--/b/x.c++` first compares `xcaxc` against `xcbxc`, and only in case of ties would the other weights (where `-` comes before `+`) would be considered.

Comment: That could be worked around by joining on `/x/` instead of `/`, but that wouldn't address the case where in the C locale on ASCII based systems, `a/foo` would sort after `a/foo.txt` for instance because `/` sorts after `.`.

Answer (score 6):

Since "`dir1` and `dir2` are arbitrary pathnames", we can't count on them consisting of a single directory (or of the same number of directories). So we need to convert the *last* slash in the pathnames to something that does not occur elsewhere in the pathname. Supposing the character `@` does not occur in your data, you can sort by basename like this:

```
cat pathnames | sed 's|\(.*\)/|\1@|' | sort -t@ -k+2 | sed 's|@|/|'
```

The first `sed` command replaces the *last* slash in each pathname with the chosen separator, the second reverses the change. (For simplicity I'm assuming the pathnames can be delivered one per line. If they are in a shell variable, convert them to one-per-line format first.)

Comment: Ha! This is great! I made it slightly more robust (and slightly uglier) by subbing a non-displaying character like so: `cat pathnames | sed 's|\(.*\)/|\1'$'\4''|' | sort -t$'\4' -k+2nr | sed 's|'$'\4''|/|'`. (I just grabbed `\4` from the ascii table. Apparently "END OF TEXT"?)

Comment: @kael, `\4` is `^D` (control-D). Unless you type it yourself at the terminal, it's an ordinary control character. In other words, safe to use in this way.

Comment: Note that the `n` in `-k+2nr` in @kael's modification makes this only work on filenames that consist only of numbers. Leave it out if the filename has other characters. (The `r` reverses the sort.)

Answer (score 5):

Sorting with **gawk** expression (supported by **bash**'s `readarray`):

Sample array of filenames containing **whitespaces**:

```
filearray=("dir1/name 0010.pdf" "dir2/name  0003.pdf" "dir3/name 0040.pdf")
```

---

```
readarray -t sortedfilearr < <(printf '%s\n' "${filearray[@]}" | awk -F'/' '
   BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"}
   { a[$0]=$NF }
   END{ for(i in a) print i}')
```

The output:

```
echo "${sortedfilearr[*]}"
dir2/name 0003.pdf dir1/name 0010.pdf dir3/name 0040.pdf
```

Accessing single item:

```
echo "${sortedfilearr[1]}"
dir1/name 0010.pdf
```

That assumes that no file path contains newline characters. Note that the numerical sorting of the values in `@val_num_asc` only applies to the leading numerical part of the key (none in this example) with fallback to lexical comparison (based on `strcmp()`, not the locale's sorting order) for ties.

Answer (score 3):

This sorts by prepending the file pathnames with the basename, sorting that numerically, and then stripping the basename from the front of the string:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
filearray=("dir1/0010.pdf" "dir2/0003.pdf" "dir3/0040.pdf" "dir4/0003.pdf")

sortarray=($(
    for file in "${filearray[@]}"
    do
        echo "$file"
    done |
        sed -r 's!^(.*)/([[:digit:]]*)(.*)$!\2 \1/\2\3!' |
        sort -t $'\t' -n |
        sed -r 's![^ ]* !!'
))

for item in "${sortarray[@]}"
do
    echo "> $item <"
done
```

It would be more efficient if you had the filenames in a list that could be passed directly through a pipe rather than as a shell array, because the actual work is done by the `sed | sort | sed` structure, but this suffices.

I first came across this technique when coding in Perl; in that language it was known as a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

In Bash the transform as given here in my code will fail if you have non-numerics in the file's basename. In Perl it could be coded far more safely.

Comment: thanks. what is a "list" in bash? Is it different from bash array? I never heard of it and it would be great. yes, storing the filenames in a "list" could be a good idea. I got the filenames as `$@` or `$*` from command line arguments for running a script

Comment: Storing the file names in a file allows for external utilities, but also risks misinterpretation of, say, newlines.

Comment: Is  Schwartzian Transform used in sorting some kind of design pattern, e.g. template, strategy, ... patterns, as introduced in the book Design Pattern by Gang of Four?

Comment: @JeffSchaller fortunately there are no newlines in numbers. If I was writing completely generic filename-safe code I quite possibly wouldn't be using bash.

Answer (score 3):

Short (and somewhat fast) solution:
By appending the array index to the filenames and sorting those, we can later create a sorted version based on the sorted indicies.

This solution only need's bash builtins as well as the `sort` binary, and also works with all filenames that don't include a newline `\n` character.

```
index=0 sortedfilearray=()
while read -r line ; do
    sortedfilearray+=("${filearray[${line##* }]}")
done <<< "$(for i in "${filearray[@]}" ; do
    echo "$(basename "$i") $((index++))"
done | sort -n)"
```

For every file, we echo its basename with its initial index appended like this:

```
0010.pdf 0
0003.pdf 1
0040.pdf 2
```

and then sent through `sort -n`.

```
0003.pdf 1
0010.pdf 0
0040.pdf 2
```

Afterwards we iterate over the output lines, extract the old index with bash variable expansion `${line##* }` and insert this element to the end of the new array.

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't require passing each file's full name to sort

Answer (score 3):

For equal depth filenames.

```
filearray=("dir1/0010.pdf" "dir2/0003.pdf" "dir3/0040.pdf" "dir3/0014.pdf")

sorted_file_array=($(printf "%s\n" "${filearray[@]}" | sort -n -t'/' -k2))
```

**Explanation**

> **-k POS1[,POS2]** -
>        The recommended, POSIX, option for specifying a sort field.  The
>        field consists of the part of the line between POS1 and POS2 (or
>        the end of the line, if POS2 is omitted), *inclusive*.  Fields and
>        character positions are numbered starting with 1.  So to sort on
>        the second field, you'd use `-k 2,2'.
>
> **-t SEPARATOR**
>        Use character SEPARATOR as the field separator when finding the
>        sort keys in each line.  By default, fields are separated by the
>        empty string between a non-whitespace character and a whitespace
>        character.

[Information is taken from the sort's man.](https://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)

**The resulting array printing**

```
printf "%s\n" "${sorted_file_array[@]}"
dir2/0003.pdf
dir1/0010.pdf
dir3/0014.pdf
dir3/0040.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing: use GNU `sed` to duplicate the last path element at the beginning, sort the lines, then strip it back off:

```
... | sed -re "s/^(.*)(\/.+)$/\2\t\1\2/p" | sort | sed -re "s/^.*\t(.*)$/\1/"
```

If you happen to be on OSX you'll need `gsed` (e.g., via `brew install gsed`) in place of `sed`.

That last part could also be, if you prefer:

```
... | grep -Po "(?<=\t).*$"
```

Comment: had hoped for exactly this, thanks for covering my laziness 