# Bash sort array according to length of elements?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort, array

Given an array of strings, I would like to sort the array according to the length of each element.

For example...

```
    array=(
    "tiny string"
    "the longest string in the list"
    "middle string"
    "medium string"
    "also a medium string"
    "short string"
    )
```

Should sort to...

```
    "the longest string in the list"
    "also a medium string"
    "medium string"
    "middle string"
    "short string"
    "tiny string"
```

(As a bonus, it would be nice if the list sorted strings of the same length, alphabetically. In the above example `medium string` was sorted before `middle string` even though they are the same length. But that's not a "hard" requirement, if it over complicates the solution).

It is OK if the array is sorted in-place (i.e. "array" is modified) or if a new sorted array is created.

Comment: some interesting answers over here, you should be able to adapt one to test for string length as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/30576368/2876682

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the strings don't contain newlines, the following should work. It sorts the indices of the array by the length, using the strings themselves as the secondary sort criterion.

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(
    "tiny string"
    "the longest string in the list"
    "middle string"
    "medium string"
    "also a medium string"
    "short string"
)
expected=(
    "the longest string in the list"
    "also a medium string"
    "medium string"
    "middle string"
    "short string"
    "tiny string"
)

indexes=( $(
    for i in "${!array[@]}" ; do
        printf '%s %s %s\n' $i "${#array[i]}" "${array[i]}"
    done | sort -nrk2,2 -rk3 | cut -f1 -d' '
))

for i in "${indexes[@]}" ; do
    sorted+=("${array[i]}")
done

diff <(echo "${expected[@]}") \
     <(echo "${sorted[@]}")
```

Note that moving to a real programming language can greatly simplify the solution, e.g. in Perl, you can just

```
sort { length $b <=> length $a or $a cmp $b } @array
```

Comment: In Python: `sorted(array, key=lambda s: (len(s), s))`

Comment: In Ruby: `array.sort { |a| a.size }`

Answer (score 11):

```
readarray -t array < <(
for str in "${array[@]}"; do
    printf '%d\t%s\n' "${#str}" "$str"
done | sort -k 1,1nr -k 2 | cut -f 2- )
```

This reads the values of the sorted array from a process substitution.

The process substitution contains a loop.  The loop output each element of the array prepended by the element's length and a tab character in-between.

The output of the loop is sorted numerically from largest to smallest (and alphabetically if the lengths are the same; use `-k 2r` in place of `-k 2` to reverse the alphabetical order) and the result of *that* is sent to `cut` which deletes the column with the string lengths.

Sort test script followed by a test run:

```
array=(
    "tiny string"
    "the longest string in the list"
    "middle string"
    "medium string"
    "also a medium string"
    "short string"
)

readarray -t array < <(
for str in "${array[@]}"; do
    printf '%d\t%s\n' "${#str}" "$str"
done | sort -k 1,1nr -k 2 | cut -f 2- )

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

```
$ bash script.sh
the longest string in the list
also a medium string
medium string
middle string
short string
tiny string
```

This assumes that the strings do not contain newlines.  On GNU systems with a recent `bash`, you can support embedded newlines in the data by using the nul-character as the record separator instead of newline:

```
readarray -d '' -t array < <(
for str in "${array[@]}"; do
    printf '%d\t%s\0' "${#str}" "$str"
done | sort -z -k 1,1nr -k 2 | cut -z -f 2- )
```

Here, the data is printed with trailing `\0` in the loop instead of newlines, the `sort` and `cut` reads nul-delimited lines through their `-z` GNU options and `readarray` finally reads the nul-delimited data with `-d ''`.

Comment: Note that `-d '\0'` is in fact `-d ''` as `bash` can't pass NUL characters to commands, even its builtins. But it does understand `-d ''` as meaning _delimit on NUL_. Note that you need bash 4.4+ for that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No, it is not `'\0'`, it is `$'\0'`. And yes, it converts (almost exactly) to `''`. But that is a way to **comunicate** to other readers the actual intent of using a NUL delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

I won't completely repeat [what I've already said about sorting in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289363/117549), just you *can* sort within bash, but maybe you shouldn't. Below is a bash-only implementation of an insertion sort, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>), and so is only tolerable for small arrays. It sorts the array elements in-place by their length, in decreasing order. It does not do a secondary alphabetical sort.

```
array=(
    "tiny string"
    "the longest string in the list"
    "middle string"
    "medium string"
    "also a medium string"
    "short string"
    )

function sort_inplace {
  local i j tmp
  for ((i=0; i <= ${#array[@]} - 2; i++))
  do
    for ((j=i + 1; j <= ${#array[@]} - 1; j++))
    do
      local ivalue jvalue
        ivalue=${#array[i]}
        jvalue=${#array[j]}
        if [[ $ivalue < $jvalue ]]
        then
                tmp=${array[i]}
                array[i]=${array[j]}
                array[j]=$tmp
        fi
    done
  done
}

echo Initial:
declare -p array

sort_inplace

echo Sorted:
declare -p array
```

As evidence that this is a specialized solution, consider the timings of the existing three answers on various size arrays:

```
# 6 elements
Choroba: 0m0.004s
Kusalananda: 0m0.004s
Jeff: 0m0.018s         ## already 4 times slower!

# 1000 elements
Choroba: 0m0.004s
Kusalananda: 0m0.004s
Jeff: 0m0.021s        ## up to 5 times slower, now!

5000 elements
Choroba: 0m0.004s
Kusalananda: 0m0.004s
Jeff: 0m0.019s

# 10000 elements
Choroba: 0m0.004s
Kusalananda: 0m0.006s
Jeff: 0m0.020s

# 99000 elements
Choroba: 0m0.015s
Kusalananda: 0m0.012s
Jeff: 0m0.119s
```

[Choroba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482395/117549) and [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482397/117549) have the right idea: compute the lengths once and use dedicated utilities for sorting and text processing.

Answer (score 4):

This also handles array elements with newlines in them; it works by passing through `sort` only the length and the index of each element. It should work with `bash` and `ksh`.

```
in=(
    "tiny string"
    "the longest
        string also containing
        newlines"
    "middle string"
    "medium string"
    "also a medium string"
    "short string"
)
out=()

unset IFS
for a in $(for i in ${!in[@]}; do echo ${#in[i]}/$i; done | sort -rn); do
        out+=("${in[${a#*/}]}")
done

printf '"%s"\n' "${out[@]}"
```

If the elements of the same length also have to be sorted lexicographically, the loop could be changed like this:

```
IFS='
'
for a in $(for i in ${!in[@]}; do printf '%s\n' "$i ${#in[i]} ${in[i]//$IFS/ }"; done | sort -k 2,2nr -k 3 | cut -d' ' -f1); do
        out+=("${in[$a]}")
done
```

This will also pass to `sort` the strings (with newlines changed to spaces), but they would still be copied from the source to the destination array by their indexes. In both examples, the `$(...)` will see only lines containing numbers (and the `/` character in the first example), so it won't be tripped by globbing characters or spaces in the strings.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. In the second example, the `$(...)` command substitution sees only the indexes (a list of numbers separated by newlines), because of the `cut -d' ' -f1` after the sort. This could be easily demonstrated by a `tee /dev/tty` at the end of the `$(...)`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I missed the `cut`.

Comment: @Isaac There's no need to quote the `${!in[@]}` or `${#in[i]}/$i` variable expansions because they only contain digits which are not subject to glob expansion and the `unset IFS` will reset the `IFS` to space, tab, newline. In fact, quoting them would be **harmful**, because it will give the false impression that such quoting is useful and effective, and that the setting of `IFS` and/or filtering the output of `sort` in the second example could be safely done away with.

Comment: @Isaac It does **NOT** break if `in` contains `"testing * here"` and `shopt -s nullglob` is set before the loop.

Answer (score 4):

A hackish? (complex) and fast one line way to sort the array by length
(**safe for newlines** and sparse arrays):

```
#!/bin/bash
in=(
    "tiny string"
    "the longest
        string also containing
        newlines"
    "middle string"
    "medium string"
    "also a medium string"
    "short string"
    "test * string"
    "*"
    "?"
    "[abc]"
)

readarray -td $'\0' sorted < <(
                    for i in "${in[@]}"
                    do     printf '%s %s\0' "${#i}" "$i";
                    done |
                            sort -bz -k1,1rn -k2 |
                            cut -zd " " -f2-
                    )

printf '%s\n' "${sorted[@]}"
```

On one line:

```
readarray -td $'\0' sorted < <(for i in "${in[@]}";do printf '%s %s\0' "${#i}" "$i"; done | sort -bz -k1,1rn -k2 | cut -zd " " -f2-)
```

On execution

```
$ ./script
the longest
        string also containing
        newlines
also a medium string
medium string
middle string
test * string
short string
tiny string
[abc]
?
*
```

Answer (score 4):

In case switching to `zsh` is an option, a hackish way there (for arrays containing any sequence of bytes):

```
array=('' blah $'x\ny\nz' $'x\0y' '1 2 3')
sorted_array=( /(e'{reply=("$array[@]")}'nOe'{REPLY=$#REPLY}') )
```

`zsh` allows defining sort orders for its glob expansion via glob qualifiers. So here, we're tricking it to do it for arbitrary arrays by globbing on `/`, but replacing `/` with the elements of the array (`e'{reply=("$array[@]")}'`) and then `n`umerically `o`rder (in reverse with uppercase `O`) the elements based on their length (`Oe'{REPLY=$#REPLY}'`).

Note that it's based on the length in number of characters. For number of bytes, set the locale to `C` (`LC_ALL=C`).

Another `bash` 4.4+ approach (assuming not too big an array):

```
readarray -td '' sorted_array < <(
  perl -l0 -e 'print for sort {length $b <=> length $a} @ARGV
              ' -- "${array[@]}")
```

(that's length in *bytes*).

With older versions of `bash`, you could always do:

```
eval "sorted_array=($(
    perl -l0 -e 'for (sort {length $b <=> length $a} @ARGV) {
      '"s/'/'\\\\''/g"'; printf " '\'%s\''", $_}' -- "${array[@]}"
  ))"
```

(which would also work with `ksh93`, `zsh`, `yash`, `mksh`).